# FreeTextBox Editor stop working after jquery post method

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Thanks in advance.

I am using FreeTextBox editor in asp.net web application.This editor works fine.

And i use jquery Post method to populate editor and other form fields' with values fetched from database. After successful post i replace the Html with updated content. All the fields gets populated but editor is not populated with value set in Post hit and it even stops working after Post hit.

Please provide any solution.

Comment: Most likely replacing the html is also replacing important events that are bound to said html.

Comment: Instead of replacing the html, try updating the html.

Comment: I replace the content with Jquery code after successful  Post hit as:                        var content = $(data).find('#divfields');                                           $("div#divfields").html(content);                                      Above "divfields" is the container which contains all the controls and i replace them with code above.How can i update them  instead of replace?

Comment: Navigate to the elements within data and get their values, then navigate to the current elements and update their values with those values.

Answer (score 0):

Which browser ? I had a similar issue, but only in Google Chrome. Also have you checked any javascript errors, when it stops working ?

Comment: All browsers.The error i found in Mozila console is as: "this.designEditor.document is null"

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and got it solved following the instructions you'll find in the following link: [Rajitha Naraveni - free textbox in update panel](http://rajithanaraveni.wordpress.com/free-textbox-in-update-panel/)